# Why after installing application from Play Store I did not get the correct version?

Tags: android, apk

I have just downloaded [Datadroid Forms Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.diomo.forms.datadroidpro) from the Play Store.

After installation it seems to show that I have downloaded the "Lite" version instead of the "Pro" version and I don't understand why this is happening. I have uninstalled and again downloaded the same app but again I get the same problem.

Issues are that I don't have all the access for this "Lite" version.

I just want to ask is there something I am missing or is there problem from application developers end?

Comment: How do you see this is the Lite version?is it just in the app name or the application is clearly the Lite version?

Comment: In the comments it says this is Lite -version and you have to purchase Pro -version to do anything meaningful. Maybe they're using in-app billing to enable Pro -version?

Comment: Yes After Downloading the App. i am getting whole app. as Lite start from the Home Screen. you can try it out by downloading the same from the playstore link. i also not getting any suggestion in application to upgrade my app to "pro" version.

Comment: @harism: No as I am not getting any kind of in-app purchase to upgrade it to pro version. i want to get enable pro version as screenshots are shown in playstore

Comment: Apparently they do check against your account when logging in to the app;  http://www.datadroid.com/index.php/pricing

Comment: @harism: Thnks for the link. so can you tell me how can i upgrade it? cz i really have no idea how can i upgrade my app. without getting anything connected to their app?